# Scenarios and steps are reported to be undefined when trying to run Behat against a feature

Tags: php, windows, cmd, bdd, behat

I'm going through the process of setting up and running behat on windows. The installation and set up where successful, now when trying to run it from CMD i get:

```
2 scenarios (2 undefined)
8 steps (8 undefined)
0m0.081s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

/**
 * @Given /^I am on "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iAmOn($arg1)
{
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

And so on.

I'm running the command:

```
 F:\Program_Files\Behat\bin>Behat F:\Program_Files\Behat\vendor\behat\mink-extension\features\search.feature
```

I think that some resource is not being reached, so there is are all the relevant directories:

```
Behat: "F:\Program_Files\Behat\bin\"
Features: "F:\Program_Files\Behat\vendor\behat\mink-extension\features\"
Feature context: "F:\Program_Files\Behat\bin\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php"
Behat config: "F:\Program_Files\Behat\bin\behat.yml"
```

Trying to place the features file here: "F:\Program_Files\Behat\bin\features\search.feature"
gives the same output.

Please let me know, how to succefully run behat against the *.feature file specified. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

when i run " >behat -dl " there is no output - I guess I'm not reaching definition expressions.

Comment: bahat.yml looks incorrect

Comment: @CiaranMcNulty - renamed it to "behat.yml". Thanks for noticing. But it did not solve the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the step definitions where missing in:

```
Behat\bin\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php
```

I was confused a bit when they ran the test script in this tutorial:
http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/behat/intro

If anyone else has this problem follow these steps here and add the step definitions manually:
http://docs.behat.org/quick_intro.html#writing-your-step-definitions

Or please check that the FeatureContext.php correctly inherits the step definitions from Mink library. You should comment out this line:

```
Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
```

Add this line:

```
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
```

And modify the FeatureContext class declaration to extend MinkContext

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext { // code here }
```